# how can i use fileinputstream to populate imageview within listView

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

I'm outputting my camera image to my sdCard using FileoutputStream, then i want to populate an imageView in a listView using fileInputStream. so here is my code note i have changed the path to one of my computer for use with the emulator.

```
public class CameraAPI extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

public Camera camera;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
CBDataBaseHelper RH;
TextView RecipeID;

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    boolean diditwork;
    try{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    RecipeID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rid2);
    String RowID;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();    
    RowID = extras.getString("SELECTED2");
    RecipeID.setText(RowID);
    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.acccam);
    SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}catch(Exception e){
    diditwork = false;
    String error = e.toString();
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("darn");
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(error);
    d.setContentView(tv);
    d.show();
}}

        public void takePhoto(View view){
            //String ID = RecipeID.getText().toString();
            //Long LID = Long.parseLong(ID);
            boolean diditwork;
            try{
            takePicture();
            }catch(Exception e){
                diditwork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("darn");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
            //String path = "/sdcard/Image.jpg";
            //RH.updateRecipe3(LID,path);

    }




public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mediaRecorder == null){
        try{
            camera = camera.open();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}



public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}

public void takePicture(){
boolean diditwork;
    try{
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }catch(Exception e){
        diditwork = false;
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("darn");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }
}


ShutterCallback shutterCallback= new ShutterCallback()
{
    public void onShutter(){

    }
};

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){

        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            try{
                outStream = new FileOutputStream("//STEFAN-PC/Users/stefan/Desktop/Uni Work/Image.jpg");
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.d("CAMERA",e.getMessage());
            }
                /*RH = new CBDataBaseHelper(CameraAPI.this);
                RH.open();
                String ID = RecipeID.getText().toString();
                Long RID = Long.parseLong(ID);
                RH.updateRecipe3(RID, data);
                RH.close();*/
            String ID = RecipeID.getText().toString();
            Long RID = Long.parseLong(ID);
            RH.updateRecipe3(RID, "/sdcard/Image.jpg");
            }







};
}
```

and then here is my code as to where i am populating the listView, can any one give me a pointer or a layout code snippet as to how i can load the image into the imageView?

```
public class CBFilter extends ListActivity {

ListView RecipeNames;
Cursor cursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
CBDataBaseHelper data;
SQLiteDatabase data2;
TextView RecipeText, RowId;
String[] from = { CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME};
int[] to = { R.id.row};
ImageView image;
byte[] dataImage;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
boolean diditwork;
try{

//java.io.FileInputStream in = openFileInput("myImage.jpg");
RecipeNames = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
RecipeNames.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
RecipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, 0, cursor, null, null);
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.RecipeImage);

data = new CBDataBaseHelper(this);
data.open();
cursor = data.query();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
RecipeNames.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




}catch(Exception e){
diditwork = false;
String error = e.toString();
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
d.setTitle("darn");
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(error);
d.setContentView(tv);
d.show();
}}

public void CreateNew(View view){

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
    long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_ROWID));
    String s = String.valueOf(rowId);
    intent1.putExtra("SELECTED", s);
    startActivity(intent1);
}


}
```

thanks Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Set the ImageView to show the image in SD Card

```
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But if you want to display the ImageView in the ListView, you have to define your own adapter for the ListView, and it would be better to use the View Holder pattern to improve the performance.

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] names;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    // static to save the reference to the outer class and to avoid access to
    // any members of the containing class
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ViewHolder will buffer the assess to the individual fields of the row
        // layout

        ViewHolder holder;
        // Recycle existing view if passed as parameter
        // This will save memory and time on Android
        // This only works if the base layout for all classes are the same
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(names[position]);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        String s = names[position];

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);           

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) about how to use View Holder pattern.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is an array adapter... this method would also work for a cursor adapter?

Comment: @StefanReaney you can read your SQLite db to get back a list of Recipe and define your custom adapter like above, otherwise you can define custom CursorAdapter which a bit different, you have to override newView and bindView, check out [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/)